# When is it safe to start using a duvet?

Tags: toddler, infant, sleep

When we brought our son home form hospital, all the advice from the midwives and health visitors was that we should not use a duvet whist he was small, and instead should use either sleep sacks (like a Grobag) or cellular blankets that are tucked in well.

At what stage can we safely progress to trying with a duvet?

Comment: In the US the recommendation is 12 months. In other countries it is different, for instance in Denmark baby duvets are used from birth.

Comment: We used sleeping bags right up to toddler-size, because being in a sleeping bag prevents one reason for crying in the night, which is that the kid has wriggled so much they're no longer covered by the covers, so they're cold. So for that reason I wouldn't be keen to switch to a duvet any sooner than you have to.

Comment: @AE Our reason for asking was because he was finding the Grobag's too warm, and we struggle to get the temperature down in the room

Comment: I see. I'd think about just using a onesie in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Germany, the official recommendation is that newborns should not use a blanket during the first year. Instead, they should sleep:

- on their back
- in a sleeping bag
- in their own bed (though in the parent's room)
- on a firm mattress
- without anything else (blankets, toys, pillows) in the bed

Source: [*Schlafempfehlungen für das 1. Lebensjahr*](http://www.kindergesundheit-info.de/index.php?eID=tx_sschpdfplus_download&dID=3310&dName=1&dHash=feb54afa), from the *Bundeszentrale für gesundheitliche Aufklärung* (a German government agency tasked with providing health information to citizens):

---

These recommendations are mainly aimed at reducing the (already small) risk of [Sudden infant death syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudden_infant_death_syndrome), because one theory is that children may get entangled in a blanket and suffocate. Sleeping bags prevent this, because they cannot be pulled over the head/face due to their cut and size.

Statistically, most cases of SIDS occur during 2-4 months of age, less frequently after 6 months of age, and only very rarely after one year. So once the child is 12 to 18 months old, there is probably no benefit to avoiding a blanket.

So my recommendation would be to start using a blanket once the child is about 18 to 24 months old, which is also when he/she will usually outgrow the sleeping bag. After 12 months, are blanket is unlikely to pose a risk, so you can start earlier if you want to.